# How do you limit a process' CPU usage on Windows? (need code, not an app)

Tags: windows, winapi, cpu-usage

There is programs that is able to limit the CPU usage of processes in Windows. For example [BES](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/) and [ThreadMaster](http://threadmaster.tripod.com/). I need to write my own program that does the same thing as these programs but with different configuration capabilities. Does anybody know how the CPU throttling of a process is done (code)? I'm not talking about setting the priority of a process, but rather how to limit it's CPU usage to for example 15% even if there is no other processes competing for CPU time.

**Update:** I need to be able to throttle any processes that is already running and that I have no source code access to.

Comment: Does your app need to be compiled for 32-bit (x86), 64-bit (x64), or both?

Comment: And do you want to do this to your own threads or to threads in other processes? And what is the use case?

Comment: The source code for BES is available, why don't you use it?

Comment: Another important clarification: are you willing to trust the process?  In other words, are you concerned with apps that would try to subvert whatever you mechanism you use for throttling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simplified, it could work somehow like this:

1. Create a periodic waitable timer with some reasonable small wait time (maybe 100ms). Get a "last" value for each relevant process by calling `GetProcessTimes` once.
2. Loop forever, blocking on the timer.
3. Each time you wake up:

   - **if** `GetProcessAffinityMask` returns 0, call `SetProcessAffinityMask(old_value)`. This means we've suspended that process in our last iteration, we're now giving it a chance to run again.
   - **else** call `GetProcessTimes` to get the "current" value
   - call `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`
   - calculate delta by subtracting last from current
   - `cpu_usage = (deltaKernelTime + deltaUserTime) / (deltaTime)`
   - **if that's more than you want** call `old_value = GetProcessAffinityMask` followed by `SetProcessAffinityMask(0)` which will take the process offline.

This is basically a very primitive version of the scheduler that runs in the kernel, implemented in userland. It puts a process "to sleep" for a small amount of time if it has used more CPU time than what you deem right. A more sophisticated measurement maybe going over a second or 5 seconds would be possible (and probably desirable).

You might be tempted to suspend all threads in the process instead. However, it is important **not** to fiddle with priorities and **not** to use `SuspendThread` unless you know exactly what a program is doing, as this can easily lead to deadlocks and other nasty side effects. Think for example of suspending a thread holding a critical section while another thread is still running and trying to acquire the same object. Or imagine your process gets swapped out in the middle of suspending a dozen threads, leaving half of them running and the other half dead.

Setting the affinity mask to zero on the other hand simply means that from now on no single thread in the process gets any more time slices on any processor. Resetting the affinity gives -- atomically, at the same time -- all threads the possibility to run again.

Unluckily, `SetProcessAffinityMask` does not return the old mask as `SetThreadAffinityMask` does, at least according to the documentation. Therefore an extra `Get...` call is necessary.

Comment: Sorry to revive a thread, but `SetProcessAffinityMask(current_process, 0)` returns `FALSE` with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` as the last error-code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If on windows 8+ it's better to use   SetInformationJobObject with JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION as described by Jerry Coffin

Comment: Is affinity 0x0 really supported? I tried under Windows 7 and the call fails with error 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER). I opened the process handle with PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION permission.

Comment: I tried using NtSetInformationProcess with ProcessAffinityMask and reference to value 0x0 but that too fails with 0xC000000D (STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Comment: 0 is not a valid parameter.

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to run the process(es) in a job object, and set the maximum CPU usage for the job object with [`SetInformationJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216.aspx), with [`JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384.aspx).

Comment: Note that this use of a Windows job object seems to have been introduced in the  Windows 8 developer preview--it is not available on Windows 7 / Server 2008 or previous releases of Windows.

Comment: This is a much better option than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

CPU usage is fairly simple to estimate using [QueryProcessCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684929%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The machine's processor speed can be obtained from HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\\~MHz (where  is the processor number, one entry for each processor present).  With these values, you can estimate your process' CPU usage and yield the CPU as necessary using Sleep() to keep your usage in bounds.